# How can I get the old chrome tabs look on modern chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs, tabs

So chrome updated its tabs along with chromium to this material design, I however, want the old one which is boxy, etc., etc.

Is this possible somehow on the modern chrome?

The flag for this is long gone under chrome://flags last seen in 2018 I believe...

This can be achieved anyhow (mods, different browser (chromium) but newest version of it)

OS: Windows 10 Home

Comment: Two words : You can't.

Answer (score 0):

Your only choice if you want the old design is to switch to Yandex Browser. It has an option to set a tab design similar to the old one Chromium had before v68? roughly.

Comment: @Chenmunka specified that it has to be a chromium based browser not chrome